# Zxing: Differentiate 128 barcodes and GSI-128

Tags: android, c++, zxing, code128, gs1-128

Using C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin, I'm developping an app to scan barcodes on an Android device. To get a barcode I call the ZXing app by Intent. When I scan a GSI-128 barcode, the return type is CODE-128. In my app, the processing is different depending on the type of barcode (128 and GSI-128).

Is there a method to differentiate these types of barcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling the Intent with `startActivityForResult(intent,0);`, just add an argument with `intent->putExtra(StringToJString("ASSUME_GS1"), true);`. If the barcode is a GS1-128, the prefix "]C1" would be add at your barcode.

```
_di_JIntent intent;
msgID = TMessageManager::DefaultManager->SubscribeToMessage(__classid(TMessageResultNotification), &retourScanTel);
intent = TJIntent::Create();
intent->setAction(StringToJString("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"));
intent->putExtra(StringToJString("ASSUME_GS1"), true);
SharedActivity()->startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

See ZXing's documentation:

[Scanning Via Intent](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent)

ZXing provides an `IntentIntegrator` class to initiate scans and parse the results.  The barcode type is in the `ScanResults.formatName` field.

If you don't want to use `IntentIntegrator`, you will have to parse the result `Intent` manually.  The barcode type is available in the Intent's `SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT` extra string field.

Either way, you can use FireMonkey's [messaging framework](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Sending_and_Receiving_Messages_Using_the_RTL) to receive the result `Intent`.  It will be wrapped inside of a `TMessageResultNotification` message.

Here is an example of ZXing scanning in Delphi from Brian Long's blog:

[Launching activities and handling results in Delphi XE6 Android apps: Scanning a bar code](http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE6AndroidActivityResult/ActivityResult.htm#BarCodeScanActivity)

```
function LaunchActivityForResult(const Intent: JIntent; RequestCode: Integer): Boolean;
var
   ResolveInfo: JResolveInfo;
begin
   ResolveInfo := SharedActivity.getPackageManager.resolveActivity(Intent, 0);
   Result := ResolveInfo <> nil;
   if Result then
     SharedActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent, RequestCode);
end;

//For more info see https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent
procedure LaunchQRScanner(RequestCode: Integer);
var
   Intent: JIntent;
begin
   Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(StringToJString('com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN'));
   Intent.setPackage(StringToJString('com.google.zxing.client.android'));
   // If you want to target QR codes
   //Intent.putExtra(StringToJString('SCAN_MODE'), StringToJString('QR_CODE_MODE'));
   if not LaunchActivityForResult(Intent, RequestCode) then
     Toast('Cannot display QR scanner', ShortToast);
end;
```

```
uses
   System.Messaging,
   ...

type
   TMainForm = class(TForm)
     ...
   private
     const ScanRequestCode = 0;
     var FMessageSubscriptionID: Integer;
     procedure HandleActivityMessage(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
     function OnActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode: Integer; Data: JIntent): Boolean;
     ...
   end;
...
uses
   FMX.Platform.Android,
   Androidapi.Helpers,
   Androidapi.JNI.App,
   Androidapi.JNI.Toast,
   LaunchActivities,
   ...
procedure TMainForm.BarcodeScannerButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   FMessageSubscriptionID := TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageResultNotification,
     HandleActivityMessage);
   LaunchQRScanner(ScanRequestCode);
end;

procedure TMainForm.HandleActivityMessage(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
begin
   if M is TMessageResultNotification then
     OnActivityResult(TMessageResultNotification(M).RequestCode, TMessageResultNotification(M).ResultCode,
       TMessageResultNotification(M).Value);
end;

function TMainForm.OnActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode: Integer; Data: JIntent): Boolean;
var
   ScanContent, ScanFormat: string;
begin
   Result :=  False;

   TMessageManager.DefaultManager.Unsubscribe(TMessageResultNotification, FMessageSubscriptionID);
   FMessageSubscriptionID := 0;

   // For more info see https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent
   if RequestCode = ScanRequestCode then
   begin
     if ResultCode = TJActivity.JavaClass.RESULT_OK then
     begin
       if Assigned(Data) then
       begin
         ScanContent := JStringToString(Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString('SCAN_RESULT')));
         ScanFormat := JStringToString(Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString('SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT')));
         Toast(Format('Found %s format barcode:'#10'%s', [ScanFormat, ScanContent]), LongToast);
       end;
     end
     else if ResultCode = TJActivity.JavaClass.RESULT_CANCELED then
     begin
       Toast('You cancelled the scan', ShortToast);
     end;
     Result :=  True;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy but I already did this but for both 128 and GSI-128 barcodes, the value of the `SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT` is the same (`CODE-128`).